# Transpose Rows and Columns after Aggregate Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database which is a list of respondents to a 54-question survey in the following format...

```
Respondent ID  Q_1   Q_2   Q_3 ... Q_54
1               5     3   [null]    2
...
3000          [null]  3     3       5
```

...and I have an aggregate query to get the count of respondents to each question...

```
Count_Q_1  Count_Q_2  Count_Q_3 ... Count_Q_54
1547       602        2999          1874
```

...and I am looking for a way to transpose the columns in the above query to get the following result...

```
   Question  Count_Respondents
   Q_1        1547
   Q_2         602
   Q_3        2999 
   ...        ...
   Q_54       1874
```

...is there any way for me to do this without 54 UNION queries (or multiple blocks of UNION queries that roll up to a master UNION query)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. Your results should've been normalized in the first place, Access doesn't support `UNPIVOT` or anything similar to it.

You can either unpivot data with many union queries, by using VBA, or by moving the data to Excel/SQL server/another program and unpivoting the results there.